# Authentication for Spring Cloud Data Flow Server

Tags: ldap, basic-authentication, spring-cloud-dataflow, apacheds, cloudfoundry-uaa

I would like to add authentication to Spring Cloud Data Flow Server application. I see articles regarding Cloud Foundry UAA with LDAP support. I tried the basic authentication snippet as well which is not working.

I see lot of references to the link https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/tree/master/security-ldap-uaa-example In that, the ldap server code is using Apache DSContainer which is deprecated and not working in my local. Is there any other approach? It's greatly appreciated if someone can provide a sample code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old sample and apache DS is there for just having easy way to get a demo running without a read ldap server. With UAA ldap is fully behind it to store users.

UAA is not a most easiest system to setup but what comes for a config that would work as a starting point to configure it with any ldap server.

Comment: PFB the portion of error stack trace I'm getting. " Error creating bean with name 'apacheDSContainer' defined in com.hillert.scdf.ldapserver.LdapserverApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/reflect/Reflection
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.1.RELEASE.jar:5.1.1.RELEASE]"   Is there any current working sample?